# first node data in LinkedList not being recognized when called

Tags: java, stack

I created a stack data structure from scratch using a linked list. It seems to `push()` properly because I can use the display method using `first.data`, and it displays the list. But when I use `peek()` I get a `NoSuchElementException` because there is an if statement  if `(first == null)`, but first should not be `null`.

I am not sure how to tackle this differently.

```
public class StackNew implements Stack{ //Stack is an interface given by my professor

private int size;

 private class Node {
        public Object data;
        public Node next;
        public Node(Object data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

private Node first = null;

public void push(Object newElement) {
    first = new Node(newElement, first);
    size++;

}
public Object peek(){
    if (first == null) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }
 return first.data;
}
public void display() {
    Node previous = null;
    while(first != null) {
        System.out.println((first.data));
        previous = first;
        first = first.next;
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StackNew stack = new StackNew();
    stack.push("java");
    stack.push(1);
    stack.push("code");

    stack.display();
    System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());
    stack.peek();

}
```

When I try to use the peek() method, the first node is null, when it should contain "code".

Comment: I recommend you clean up your code a bit. As of now it's not even compiling because you're trying to implement a class (Stack) instead of an Interface. It also has unused variables and the method push returns the wrong type. I don't even see how you managed to compile and run this in its current state. That said, Amardeep's answer is probably correct for the code that you *actually* tried to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you would notice that you are getting the error only when you call `display` method.

This is because in your implementation, you are overwriting the `first` to `first.next` which ultimately becomes null in the last iteration of the `while` loop. So you need a new pointer that will keep track of the current element and that will progress to the next element without impacting the `first` pointer.

So you need to correct the `display` method to:

```
 public void display() {
      Node current = first;
      while(current != null) {
          System.out.println((current.data));
          current = current.next;
      }
 }
```

Here a new pointer `current` will keep track of the current element and in the while loop will consecutively print the elements.

Some other issues in your code (if you are trying to extend `java.util.Stack`):

1. You are trying to `implement` the `Stack` class, but in fact you should `extend` it.
2. In order to use `isEmpty()` from the `Stack` class you need to increment the `elementCount++;` in the `push()`  method instead of `size`. As `isEmpty()` checks `elementCount` inherited from the `Stack` class.
3. The return type of `push` should not be `void` instead it should return the argument. (as per the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push(E)) of the `Stack` class).

   ```
   @Override
   public Object push(Object newElement) {
        first = new Node(newElement, first);
        elementCount++;
        return newElement;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but part of the assignment is to use an interface, and the push method given is void, but I was asking for my peek() and pop() methods are getting errors on first.data lines.

Comment: @JoshPehling your peek method was throwing `NoSuchElementException` right? that was because you were setting the first pointer to `null` in the `display` method. If you fix the `display` method and then call `peek` you would not get that exception anymore.

Comment: Ahhh I see, because the node previous was null, and I set first to previous. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoshPehling Glad I could help out!